# WPF _ TextBlock Vertical ScrollBar issue

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, vertical-scrolling

I have a stackpanel like in the following.

```
    <Stackpanel>
         <Grid>
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <RowDefinition/>
                 <RowDefinition/>
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         < TextBlock Text="SomeText"  Grid.Row="0"/>

         <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >

             <TextBlock Text="Some Other Text"/>
       </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

I want the second text block to have a vertical scroll bar. But it does not show the vertical scroll bar. Does anyone know what the issue is ?

Comment: It will show a scroll bar like this, set height to textblock 2 to be sure, but that will be disabled as there is nothing in scroll viewer to scroll

Comment: explain your requirement first, that might give us an idea about what are you trying to do, because this doesn't look right approach.

Answer (score 2):

This one working Try this   .cs page add this line    txt1.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel x:Name="RightPanel"
                    Margin="5,0"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="50" x:Name="txt1"  Text="Some Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other Text"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (set ScrollViewer Width and Height and TextWrapping in TextBox):

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
              Width="70" Height="50">
     <TextBlock Text="Some Other Text tststssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" 
                TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get rid of the `stackpanel`
2. Add `Height`s to the `RowDefinition`s
3. Set `TextWrapping` for the `TextBlock`

So your code should look like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="SomeText"  Grid.Row="0"/>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other TextSome Other Text"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```